# localizable strings C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im thinking about solution which would give mechanizm to localize applications websties etc. On one od the cms I saw option that each time u use localizable string simply put

[LANG::MyText]

and then according to language (each one in different file) tags were replaced.

Should it be done in procompile stage? Or is it something else.

What about aspx pages. Is it possible to do it in simillar way

not put:

```
<asp:Label test="myTextInEnglish>...
```

but

```
<asp:Label text="[LANG:MyText]" ...
```

I hope that my question is clear

thanks for help

Comment: relevant one in the past [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257221/asp-net-multilingual-web-application-localization)
, [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192465/how-to-localize-asp-net-mvc-application)
, [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209831/asp-net-localization-with-page-methods-web-services-via-ajax/210802)
, [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818631/globalization-and-localization-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use built in .NET features? Use Cultures

Good to read:

- [ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx)
- [Globalization and Localization in .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ankithakur/globalization_localization_in_dotnet_csharp07032006023510am/globalization_localization_in_dotnet_csharp.aspx)

*From MSDN*

> Globalization is the process of
>   designing and developing applications
>   that function for multiple cultures.
>   Localization is the process of
>   customizing your application for a
>   given culture and locale.

These topics are the key to create (ASP).NET Web applications that can be adapted to different languages and cultures, which I suppose is what you are after.